# SQL optimization (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I know it´s difficult to answer without knowing the model, but I have next heavy query that takes around 10 secs to complete in my MySQL database. I guess it can be optimized, but I´m not that skilled.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b . *
FROM
    boats b,
    states s,
    boat_people bp,
    countries c,
    provinces pr,
    cities ct1,
    cities ct2,
    ports p,
    addresses a,
    translations t,
    element_types et
WHERE
    s.name = 'Confirmed' AND bp.id = '2'
        AND b.state_id = s.id
        AND b.id NOT IN (SELECT 
            bc.boat_id
        FROM
            boat_calendars bc
        WHERE
            (date(bc.since) <= '2015-02-09 09:23:00 +0100'
                AND date(bc.until) >= '2015-02-09 09:23:00 +0100')
                OR (date(bc.since) <= '2015-02-10 09:23:00 +0100'
                AND date(bc.until) >= '2015-02-10 09:23:00 +0100'))
        AND b.people_capacity_id >= bp.id
        AND c.id = (SELECT DISTINCT
            t.element_id
        FROM
            translations t,
            element_types et
        WHERE
            t.element_translation = 'Spain'
                AND et.name = 'Country'
                AND t.element_type_id = et.id)
        AND pr.country_id = c.id
        AND pr.id = (SELECT DISTINCT
            t.element_id
        FROM
            translations t,
            element_types et
        WHERE
            t.element_translation = 'Mallorca'
                AND et.name = 'Province'
                AND t.element_type_id = et.id)
        AND ((ct1.province_id = pr.id AND p.city_id = ct1.id AND b.port_id = p.id)
        OR (ct2.province_id = pr.id AND a.city_id = ct2.id AND b.address_id = a.id));
```

Basically, it tries to get all the boats, that are not already booked in Confirmed state and that are in a province and a country ie. Mallorca, Spain.

Please, let me know if you need some more details about de purpose of the query or the model.

Comment: remove `*` instead give `column names` in `select` statement.  it will increase some performance. Its one of the way to optimize

Comment: do you have indexes defined on joined columns?

Comment: You have cross joins against _translations_ and _element_types_ . Neither of these tables are used in the main query and there is no join condition against them to limit the joins.

Comment: Fix your query to have proper, explicit `join` syntax.  First, it is hard to understand.  Second, you could be missing `join` conditions between tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove * from select clause. instead give column names in select clause. it will increase some 
>   performance. Its one of the way to optimize

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a sub query, use **`LEFT JOIN NULL`** (just google for it) and it will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All your answers are good. But, according to @POHH suggestions, I increased the performance magically by just replacing the b.* for b.somecolumnsnames.

From 10 to 1 or 2 secs.

Comment: you can check it as answer then ... :p